# How to create an ArcObjects point with Latitude and Longitude

Tags: esri, arcgis-server

I need to add a point in an existing feature class using .NET API of ArcGIS Server 10 in  C# (Visual Studio 2008). I'm using a sample from ESRI Resource Center (ArcGIS_SimpleEdit_CSharp). The following shows the portion of the code that creates the new point using X/Y coordinates.

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint aoPoint = serverContext.CreateObject("esriGeometry.Point") as 
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint;
aoPoint.PutCoords(actionRecord.Location.X, actionRecord.Location.Y);
```

But I need to use Latitude and Longitude (with decimal precision) instead of X/Y coordinates. How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If your data is in Latitude/Longitude and your feature class is in some projected coordinate system, then you need to *project* your lat/long data before adding the points to your feature class. For this you would want to use the IGeometry.Project method, which you can find more information about [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Project5_Method/002m000001rz000000/).

Be aware that depending on the datum of your latitude/longitude data, as well as that of your feature class, you may need to perform a *datum transformation* as part of the projection process. In that case you would want the IGeometry.ProjectEx method (more info [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ITransformation_Interface/002m000003wt000000/) and [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ITransformation_Interface/002m000003wt000000/) - note the latter link includes links to some samples at the bottom which may be helpful).

I know this is not a complete answer, but hopefully I've provided a couple pointers to get you going in the right direction. If you can provide a little more detail on what exactly you are trying to do, then perhaps I can provide some more specific help.

One last point - it appears you are using the ArcGIS Server Web ADF here - are you aware that the Web ADF local connections are going away at version 10.1 of Server?  Depending on the nature of your project, you may want to consider an alternate approach, such as using the SOAP or REST APIs, Geoprocessing services, and/or writing Server Object Extensions (SOEs) for any work that really requires custom ArcObjects.